# inline styling in js not working for new window

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

I am trying to have a function validate an email address as well as take all the input from within a form tag from the html input. I am trying to create a resume within a new window. Ie; enter name, address, career objectives, etc.

I have been working on this function for quite some time, using different methods.

```
//html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Web 115 Final Project</title>

</head>

<body>
    <script src="projectJS.js"></script>
    <form id = "myForm">
        <label for="name">Enter Your Full Name</label><br>
        <input type = "text" id="name" ><br><br>

        <label for="address">Enter Your Address</label><br>
        <input type = "text" id="address" ><br><br>

        <label for="phone">Enter Your Phone Number</label><br>
        <input type = "text" id="phone" ><br><br>

        <label for="email">Enter Your Email Address</label><br>
        <input type = "text" id="email" ><br><br>

        <label for="objectives">Enter Your Career Objectives</label><br>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="objectives"></textarea><br><br>

        <label for="personalInfo">Enter Your Personal Information</label><br>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="personalInfo"></textarea><br><br>

        <label for="education">Enter Your Educational Background</label><br>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="education"></textarea><br><br>

        <label for="employment1">Enter Your Most Recent Employment Start/End Date</label><br>
        <input type="date" id="employment1"><br><br>
        <label for="description1">Describe This Employment Experience</label><br>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="description1"></textarea><br><br>

        <label for="employment2">Enter Your Second Most Recent Employment Start/End Date</label><br>
        <input type="date" id="employment2"><br><br>
        <label for="description2">Describe This Employment Experience</label><br>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="description2"></textarea><br><br>

        <label for="employment3">Enter Your Third Most Recent Employment Start/End Date</label><br>
        <input type="date" id="employment3"><br><br>
        <label for="description3">Describe This Employment Experience</label><br>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="description3"></textarea><br><br>

        <label for="employment4">Enter Your Forth Most Recent Employment Start/End Date</label><br>
        <input type="date" id="employment4"><br><br>
        <label for="description4">Describe This Employment Experience</label><br>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="description4"></textarea><br><br>

        <label for="references">Enter Your Business References</label><br>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="references"></textarea><br><br>


        <input type="button" onclick="validateEmail()" value="Create Resume">

</form>

</body>

</html>
//js
var elemH1 = document.createElement("h1");
elemH1.style.color = "red";
elemH1.style.fontFamily = "tahoma";
elemH1.style.textAlign = "center";
elemH1.innerText = "Kent Butler";
document.body.appendChild(elemH1);

var elemH2 = document.createElement("h2");
elemH2.style.fontFamily = "garamond";
elemH2.style.color = "red";
elemH2.style.fontStyle = "italic";
elemH2.style.textAlign = "center";
elemH2.innerText = "WEB 115.0001";
document.body.appendChild(elemH2);

var title = document.createElement("h1");
title.style.textAlign = "center";
title.innerText = "Build Your Resume";
document.body.appendChild(title);

function validateEmail(email) {
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value; //get email id
    //var personalInfo = document.getElementById('personalInfo').value;
    var objectives = document.getElementById('objectives').value;
    objectives.style.textAlign = "right";
    //var education = document.getElementById('education').value;
    var re = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
    var testRe = re.test(email);
    testRe;
    if (testRe != true) {
        window.alert("Invalid Email Address. Please Reenter");
    }
    else {
        var myText = ('<html>\n<head>\n<title>Resume</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n');
        myText += (name + "<br>" + address + " " + phone + " / " + email + "<br><br>");
        myText += ("CAREER OBJECTIVES" + objectives)
        myText += ("</body>\n</html>");

        var openWindow = window.open('');
        openWindow.document.write(myText);
    }
}
```

This is not the finished product. I have a number of other fields to create, but that is not going to be an issue. I need to be able to style the new document ie align text right. The resume product should have "CAREER OBJECTIVES" aligned left, and then the input from the html aligned right. The "objectives.style.textAlign = "right";" isnt working (line 28 in the JS)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
var objectives = document.getElementById('objectives');
```

rather than the value

Comment: If I do it that way, the html does not send the input to the new document.

Comment: @KButler it seems to me that you are mixing business logic and presentation in your javascript - why not use a CSS file for your resume document?

Comment: @KButler the way you have it now, context is lost, so the styling doesn't apply to your new window. You could try adding the style (truly) inline to your "myText" var eg. something like myText += ("<p style='text-align: right;'>CAREER OBJECTIVES" + objectives</p>)